# What is the correct form for string.replace?

Tags: python, string, replace

Following the Python documentation for string.replace ( http://docs.python.org/library/string.html ):

> string.replace(str, old, new[, maxreplace])
>
> Return a copy of string str with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

Using the format as given generates the following error:

```
>>> a = 'grateful'
>>> a.replace(a,'t','c')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

It seems odd that you'd need the "str" repeated and from the error I guessed that my third argument was being taken for maxreplace.

The format:

> string.replace(old, new)

does seem to function as expected.

I'm wondering if I am misunderstanding something, and the form given in the Python documentation is, in fact, correct in some way.

Comment: "Using the format as given generates the following error". Could you show us the line you used to generate that error?

Comment: You haven't given the lines; literally calling `string.replace(old, new)` throws a `TypeError: replace() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)`.

Comment: btw, pretty amazing the quality and thoroughness of answers one gets even in the first 10 minutes on this site. i'm impressed. seems like a very supportive community.

Comment: Well, when you ask good questions (even good questions with a flaw, as in your case), people can give good answers. Try asking a question that doesn't have nearly enough information to figure out what you want, and you'll get a very different experience. :) But overall, I think this site works very well.

Comment: Why'd I get a downvote on the question, btw?

Comment: My guess would be that someone downvoted you for the reasons in Kevin's comment (since that comment has 3 upvotes), and hasn't been back since you edited the question. But there's really no way to be sure. I wouldn't get too worked up over downvotes (especially when you've got two upvotes); getting the question into the most usable state for future searchers is far more important than getting the most votes, and getting the answer you need is even more important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your confusion here (and that of most of the answers) is the different between the `string` module and the `str` built-in class. They're entirely separate things, even if there is a lot of overlap in functionality.

`string.replace(s, old, new)` is a free function, not a method. There's no way you can call it as `s.replace(old, new)`, because `s` cannot be an instance of the `string` module.

`str.replace(self, old, new)` is a method. As with any other method (other than classmethod and staticmethod methods), you can—and usually do—call it through a `str` instance, as `s.replace(old, new)`, where `s` becomes the `self` parameter automatically.

You can also call a method through the class, so `str.replace(s, old, new)` turns out to be exactly the same as `s.replace(old, new)`. And it just so happens that, if `s` is a `str`, this does the exact same thing as `string.replace(old, new)`. But that's really a coincidence that's true for historical reasons.

As a side note, you almost never want to call functions in the `string` module. They're mostly a holdover from very early versions of Python. In fact, `string.replace` is listed under the "Deprecated string functions" section in the documentation, as are most of the other functions you'd probably go looking for there. The reason the whole module hasn't been deprecated is that it has some things that don't belong in the `str` (or `bytes` or `unicode`) class, such as constants like `string.digits`.

Comment: +1 this is a good explanation, now I totally got it what the OP was confused with.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it led me to find the root cause, which is that I was in the "deprecated" section of the manual. I should have been here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

The presence of string.split() just above led to the misunderstanding.  Great answer.

Comment: @marccenedella use the `string`  module only for constants like `ascii_lowercase`, `ascii_uppercase` etc, otherwise it's not necessary.

Comment: "You're not using string.replace here, youvoting're using str.replace" as you said yourself.... boo to downvoting two other answerers who said exactly the same thing as you.

Comment: @hayden: I'm using both `string.replace` and `str.replace`, and explaining the difference (in the very first sentence).

Comment: @hayden: No, you don't explain the difference. You explain the difference between calling `str.replace` as a standalone function vs. as a bound method, and then at one point add to the confusion by calling that method `string.replace`. Other people did edit their answers to be clear; I un-downvoted Ashwini's answer and then upvoted it before he deleted it. But yours is still wrong. I suspect that you still don't realize there are two different functions here, no matter how many times it's explained.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that doc is correct, since it is referring to using `string.replace()` as a *stand alone function*. So you can do this:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.replace("a","a","b")
'b'
```

This is different from calling `replace()` as a *method of a given string*, like this:

```
>>> 'a'.replace('a','b')
'b'
```

They are two different things that have different syntax but are designed to have the same results. So calling one with the other's syntax will result in an error. For example:

```
>>> 'a'.replace('a','a','b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: These are not the same thing; one is the free function `replace` in the module `string`; the other is the method `replace` on the class `str`.

Comment: @abarnert I was trying to say they weren't the same... How could I edit to make that clearer?

Comment: The problem is that you refer to "calling it [`string.replace`] as a method of a given string", which is impossible. `string.replace` is not a method of strings; `str.replace` is. The only reason it's possible to get away with confusing them that they happen to have the same effect, but they're in no way the same thing. With some minor edits your description would be correct as an explanation of the difference between calling `str.replace()` as a standalone function vs. as a bound method, but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: The edited version is no longer incorrect, but it doesn't really explain things. The issue isn't just calling one function standalone and another as a method, but also that they're two completely different functions. Since the OP has confused both things, I think you really need to show all three possibilities (`string.replace`, `str.replace` as a bound method, and the unusual `str.replace` with an explicit `str` instance in place of `self`) to clear things up.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah I fixed the vague "it," thanks. Your answer does a good job of explaining the difference; I'll leave mine up just to show some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're confusing the 'replace' method of the string module with the 'replace' method of a python string.

```
string.replace("rest,"r", "t")
```

will return "test"

```
"rest".replace("r", "t")
```

will return "test"

```
"rest".replace("rest", "r", "t")
```

will return the error you mention

Comment: Very brief but very good answer for me.  Helped me to get to the right answer with the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Python methods use an explicit self. That is to say, where C++ / javscript have a magic `this` variable, Python passes it explicitly as the first argument. When you call the method, the object to the left of the dot becomes the first argument of the method.

These are equivalent:

```
str.replace('foobar', 'o', 'O', 1)

'foobar'.replace('o', 'O', 1)
```

You see that there are just four values (and one class: `str`) involved in both cases.

Comment: The OP is asking about `string.replace`, which is not the same thing as `str.replace`.

Comment: +1 These are equivalent, and this is the OPs entire point of confusion.

Comment: @hayden: They're not equivalent; they're two entirely separate functions that happen to have the same effect. Ashwini Chaudhary may have explained that better than me, if you still don't get it (although it looks like he deleted his answer since then, sadly).

Answer (score 0):

## Update for latest syntax

for now is **2021** year

### the latest official doc

move to here: [string replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

### corresponding python code (in `VSCode`) syntax notice

[image]

which syntax is:

> str.replace(self: str, old, new, count) -> str

## Answer for: `It seems odd that you'd need the "str" repeated`

not odd, after you know the details:

- Python's builtin **String Class** named: **str**

-> `str.replace(old, new[, count])` has two normal use case:

### Use case 1: use builtin string class `str`

```py
originalStr = 'grateful'
replacedStr = str.replace(originalStr,'t','c')
```

### Use case 2: use `string variable` itself

```py
originalStr = 'grateful'
replacedStr = originalStr.replace('t','c')
```

## Answer for: `TypeError: an integer is required`

your (error) code:

```py
a = 'grateful'
a.replace(a,'t','c')
```

's explanation:

`a.replace(a,'t','c')`

match above **Use case 2** 's syntax:

`strVariable.replace(old, new[, count])`

so:

- `'a'` => `strVariable`
- `'a'` => `old`
- `'t'` => `new`
- `'c'` => optional `count`

but `'c'` is **str**, not (expected) **int**, so report error:

> TypeError: an integer is required

## How to change my code?

as above said, change your code to:

### Use case 1: use builtin string class `str`

```py
originalStr = 'grateful'
replacedStr = str.replace(originalStr,'t','c')
```

### Use case 2: use `string variable` itself

```py
originalStr = 'grateful'
replacedStr = originalStr.replace('t','c')
```