# Python String Replace Error

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a python script that keeps returning the following error:

> TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing this.

Here is part of my code:

```
inHandler = open(inFile2, 'r')
outHandler = open(outFile2, 'w')

for line in inHandler:

    str = str.replace("set([u'", "")
    str = str.replace("'", "")
    str = str.replace("u'", "")
    str = str.replace("'])", "")

outHandler.write(str)

inHandler.close()
outHandler.close()
```

Everything that is seen within double quotations needs to be replaced with nothing.

So `set([u'` should look like

Comment: 1st using `str` as varibale is very bad practive, `str` is inbuilt function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
for line in inHandler:
    line = line.replace("set([u'", "")
    line = line.replace("'", "")
    line = line.replace("u'", "")
    line = line.replace("'])", "")

outHandler.write(line)
```

On the documentation, wherever it says something like `str.replace(old,new[,count])` the `str` is an example variable. In fact, `str` is an inbuilt function, meaning you never want to change what it means by assigning it to anything.

```
line = line.replace("set([u'", "")
  ^This sets the string equal to the new, improved string.

line = line.replace("set([u'", "")
        ^ This is the string of what you want to change.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to call `replace`.

Let us start by defining a string:

```
In [19]: s = "set([u'"
```

We can call the `replace` method of string `s`:

```
In [20]: s.replace("u'", "")
Out[20]: 'set(['
```

Or, we can call the `replace` of the class `str`:

```
In [21]: str.replace(s, "u'", "")
Out[21]: 'set(['
```

The latter way requires three arguments because `str`.  That is why you received the error about missing arguments.

#### What went wrong

Consider the code:

```
for line in inHandler:

    str = str.replace("set([u'", "")
    str = str.replace("'", "")
    str = str.replace("u'", "")
    str = str.replace("'])", "")
```

First, note the goal is to replace text in `line` but nowhere in the calls to `replace` is the variable `line` used for anything.

The first call to replace generates the error:

```
>>> str.replace("set([u'", "")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Used in the above form, `str.replace` interprets its first argument as the string to replace.  It is as if you wrote:

```
"set([u'".replace("")
```

In other words, it thinks that `set([u'` is the string to operate on and the replace function was given just one argument: the empty string.  That it why the message is `replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`.

What you need is to operate on the variable `line`:

```
line = line.replace("set([u'", "")
```

And so on for the remaining lines in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Conclusion: you have two issue:

- **error**: wrong syntax for `str.replace`
- **abuse**: the Python reserved key `str`

## error: wrong syntax for `str.replace`

for error `TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

the root cause is:

your code

```py
str = str.replace("set([u'", "")
```

intension is to use `str.replace` do replace work

the correct (one) syntax is:

```py
newStr = oldStr.replace(fromStr, toStr[, replaceCount])
```

corresponding to your code, could be:

```py
replacedLine = line.replace("set([u'", "")
```

Note: another syntax is:

```py
newStr = str.replace(oldStr, fromStr, toStr[, replaceCount])
```

for full details please refer [another post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501100/what-is-the-correct-form-for-string-replace/66997812#66997812)

## abuse: the Python reserved key `str`

- background knowledge

  - `str` is Python reserved key word

    - means: **the name of String class** in `Python 3`

      - `str` has many **builtin** functions

        - such as: [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), [str.lower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)
    - also means: you should **NOT** use `str` as **normal `variable`/`function` name**

so your code:

```py
for line in inHandler:
    str = str.replace("set([u'", "")
```

**should** change to (something like this):

```py
for line in inHandler:
    newLine = line.replace("set([u'", "")
```

or

```py
for line in inHandler:
    newLine = str.replace(line, "set([u'", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
for s in inHandler:

    s = s.replace("set([u'", " ")  ## notice the space between the quotes
    s = s.replace("'", " ")
    s = s.replace("u'", " ")
    s = s.replace("'])", " ")
```

Please refrain from using built-in data types as variables (like you have used `str`).

Answer (score 0):

You could compress the four lines of `replace` code

```
str = str.replace("set([u'", "")
str = str.replace("'", "")
str = str.replace("u'", "")
str = str.replace("'])", "")
```

as,

```
str = re.sub(r"set\(\[u'|u'|'\]\)|'", r"", str)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "foo set([u'bar'foobaru''])"
>>> string = re.sub(r"set\(\[u'|u'|'\]\)|'", r"", string)
>>> string
'foo barfoobar'
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as below:

```
inHandler = open('test.txt', 'r')
outHandler = open('test1.txt', 'w')
data = ''
for line in inHandler.readlines():
    print 'src:' + line
    line = line.replace("set([u'", "")
    line = line.replace("u'", "")
    line = line.replace("'])", "")
    line = line.replace("'", "")
    data += line
    print 'replace:' + line
outHandler.write(data)

inHandler.close()
outHandler.close()
```

And I tested it. Result:

```
src:set([u'adg',u'dafasdf'])
replace:adg,dafasdf
src:set([u'adg',u'dafasdf'])
replace:adg,dafasdf
src:set([u'adg',u'dafasdf'])
replace:adg,dafasdf
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are referring to [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) (string) inbuild function in python then

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
    Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. 
    If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Means you need to give 2 values.

And you are using `line` as variable so you can try.

```
local_string = ''
for line in inHandler:
    local_string = line
    local_string = local_string.replace("set([u'", "")
    local_string = local_string.replace("'", "")
    local_string = local_string.replace("u'", "")
    local_string = local_string.replace("'])", "")
```